# Do While Looping

Tags: vba

I have this code below that looks at 200+ files on C: drive......then I am looking for values starting at row 3....look over to col P.....COL P contains values? "yes" then copy entire row.....(if there is a value P col in any cell...then it notices it) ....goes to that row of col P.....copies entire row dependent upon col P values....(if value exists grab row based on Col P in C drive files) and copies that row only to a new file.....on the desktop...closes that desktop file and moves to next file line searching for data in Col P....to copy row to desktop file...over and over.............I cannot get it to move to the next file or the next reconized value in P col of C files.......only does ONE file.....need it to go to the next one in the stack of 200 files in C drive searching each row for value in Col P....copy entire row and add it to that desktop file where the first data point is..neatly under that last data point (have that working)   At the end it gives me a msg box that says "x amount of files searched"   Most of it works.  Can figure out where my "next" should go corresponding to my For statement ..nor can I figure out where my Loop should go for either "Do" statment (do while and do until)  I think I have too much going on.....please help correct Thanks.

```
Sub copy_to_new_sheet_clump()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
Dim count As Integer
path = "C:\Ben_Excel4\"
filename = Dir(path & "*.xls*")
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
Do Until Len(filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
count = count + 1   ' this is to count all files for msg box at end
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & filename) ' looking in 200+ files in C:

'assuming the data being searched for is in Equipment Sheet
Sheets("Equipment").Select    ' this is correct sheet for 200+ files in C:
' get end of rows / number of rows to look at by looking down COL P to end
rowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For i = 3 To rowCount  ' starting at row three search P column for data
                      'assuming the number is contained in a cell on COL P
Range("P" & i).Select
ActiveCell.Select
'have data and find bottom of active sheet and paste one row below last data pasted
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty

Selection.EntireRow.Select
' there are hyperlinks have to get rid of on the sheet...ha...dont ask. 
Selection.Hyperlinks.Delete   

Selection.EntireRow.Copy   'copy whats found in Col P 

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'saves to desk top file where all the rows for files searched that have data 
 ' in col P and stacks it nicely in this Book1.xls on desktop  sheet 1          

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\patrickf\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")  
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A4").Select    'starts at row 4 for pasting
rowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a" & rowCount + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PastE
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\Users\patrickf\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close   'saves desktop file and closes it....
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Exit Do

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Loop   

MY ISSUE =  'somehow need it to go to NEXT file in C drive out of the 200
            '  sitting there and search by Col P for "not empty" ....grab
            '   row...paste to desktop file....then next file.

MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"
```

Comment: You should probably edit that "paragraph" of text, as it's quite difficult to follow now. Lack of newlines, proper sentences, and 14 consecutive periods don't help.

Comment: is this all of your code ? you have `For i = 3 To rowCount` without the `Next` ? the same with `Do Until Len(filename) > 0` and `Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty` you have only one `Loop`, it's hard to understand where are you missing the closing statement and which logic's actually belongs to which loop, upload all of your relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should be more or less there:

```
Sub copy_to_new_sheet_clump()

    'use a constant for fixed values
    Const FOLDER As String = "C:\Ben_Excel4\"
    Const SHT_SOURCE As String = "Equipment"
    Const WB_DEST As String = "C:\Users\patrickf\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
    Const SHT_DEST As String = "Sheet1"

    Dim wbk As Workbook, f As String, shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim count As Integer, wbDest As Workbook, rngDest As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(WB_DEST)

    'set the first destination row
    Set rngDest = wbDest.Sheets(SHT_DEST).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    count = 0

    f = Dir(FOLDER & "*.xls*")
    Do While Len(f) > 0

        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & f, ReadOnly:=True)
        Set shtSrc = wbk.Sheets(SHT_SOURCE)

        For i = 3 To shtSrc.Cells(shtSrc.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With shtSrc.Rows(i)
                'any value in Col P ?
                If .Cells(1, "P").Value <> "" Then
                    .Hyperlinks.Delete
                    .Copy rngDest                      'copy the row
                    Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next paste row in destination sheet
                End If
            End With
        Next i

        wbk.Close False 'no save

        count = count + 1
        f = Dir() 'next file (if any)
    Loop

    wbDest.Close True 'save changes

    MsgBox count & " : files found in folder '" & FOLDER & "'"

End Sub
```